Multiple squashfs used in Ubuntu 24.04 live ISO
I'll keep this question very brief and generic since I think it applies to anyone trying to modify an official Ubuntu 24.04 ISO that will use it only in the "Try Ubuntu" mode.
The "/casper" directory of any official Ubuntu 24.04 ISO contains at least two squashfs files, but it can contain more. For Xubuntu 24.04 Minimal, they are named: "minimal.live.squashfs" and "minimal.squashfs". From what I've investigated, minimal.squashfs seems to be the squashfs used for an install while the minimal.live.squashfs seems to be a partial squashfs used by casper to support the live session. Thus, when booting the ISO in live mode: minimal.squashfs is mounted to "/rofs" and a COW filesystem overlay is used for minimal.live.squashfs and is mounted into the "/" directory.
You can't easily use chroot on "minimal.live.squashfs" in the ISO to add packages because it's only a partial squashfs and tools like Cubic will default to selecting "minimal.squashfs". Thus you are left with using 'apt-get install' on minimal.squashfs. As previously mentioned, if you run the ISO using the "try Ubuntu" mode, minimal.live.squashfs is mounted to the "/" directory which seems to present a problem because dpkg or apt-get will only see packages in minimal.live.squashfs and not in minimal.squashfs - thus you can mistakenly double-install packages, can't run apt-get upgrade on minimal.squashfs (I am aware the upgrade will not survive a reboot) or view packages you installed into minimal.squashfs - but you can still run them however.
Is my understanding correct? If so, does anyone know what the proper way to modify the ISO for the live "try Ubuntu" is?

It is not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to make a persistent live USB? There are tools for that. Are you trying to modify the official ISO and add other apps? That question has been asked before.

When adding your apps using Cubic, you will see all of them in the live session, and they will still be present after installation if you use this modified version.
